# How do messenger fields break SUSY in the MSSM?

Tags: supersymmetry

I have been reading the notes on Supersymmetry by Martin. I am trying to understand gauge mediated symmetry breaking. From what I understand, there is a hidden sector where SUSY is spontaneously broken, there is a messenger superfield and there is a visible sector. There should be no direct coupling between the hidden sector and the visible sector. The spontaneous susy breaking in the hidden sector affects the messenger fields which in turn breaks susy in the visible sector keeping the soft terms. The messenger fields break susy in the visible sector only via loops. This is the bit I do not understand. In the superpotential, I don't see terms where there is an interaction between the messenger fields and the visible sector. Is this something to do with the covariant derivatives? Also why do these messenger terms only appear in loops in the visible sector?